# Why my code is getting Runtime error?

Tags: c, runtime

It took me 3 hrs to get the logic to solve the question and code accordingly. But now I am

getting this runtime error. Can anyone please help me to know what mistake I am doing ?
Edit : Its running now but not printing anything.

http://ideone.com/2YlS9J

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float distance(float n1,float m1,float n2,float m2){
   float d=0;float sum=0;
   d =sqrt(pow(m2-m1,2)+pow(n2-n1,2));
   sum+=d;
   printf("%.2f",sum);
   return sum;
}

int main(void) {
   int t,n,i,j;float sum=0;
   scanf("%d",&t);
   while(t--){
      scanf("%d",&n);
      int r=0,s=0,a=0,b=0;
      int x[n],y[n],p[n],q[n],min[n],max[n];
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         scanf("%d %d",&x[i],&y[i]);}

      for(j=0;j<10001;j++){
         for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(j==x[i]){
               p[r++]=x[i];q[s++]=y[i];
            }
         }}
         for(i=0,j=i+1;i<n,j<n;i++,j++){
            if(p[i]==p[j]){
               if(q[i]>q[j]){min[a++]=p[i]; max[b++]=q[i];}
               else{min[a++]=p[i]; max[b++]=q[j];}
            }
            else{min[a++]=p[i]; max[b++]=q[i];}
         }

      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         distance(min[i],max[i],min[i+1],max[i+1]);
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
        int x[n],y[n],p[n],q[n],min[n],max[n];
```

is not correct. In C/C++ you cannot declare plain arrays of a variable size (unlike, say, in Basic). The size of such an array **must** be known at compile time.

Possible solutions are:

1. Use dynamic memory (`malloc()`/`free()`)
2. Use a statically allocated arrays with a set maximum size (and either run a risk of buffer overflow and memory corruption or **make sure** you use no-more-than the space you have allocated for)
3. Use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: C99, unlike C++ has VLA support.

Comment: ok..that problem is solved, i have given a const. size 100002. Now program is running successfully but not printing anything. What's wrong now ?

Comment: You should really use a debugger to answer those types of questions

Comment: hmm..so you have no idea ?

Comment: If you don't want to use a debugger to find problems in your own code I see no reason for **anyone** to spend any time trying to help you

Comment: Actually I am a beginner. Fine I'll use a debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry you are taking it negatively. The use of a debugger is **not** a punishment but an essential tool that any software engineer **has** to use every day

Comment: Not every tool is available online.I personally am not aware of any online C/C++ debuggers. However for Windows users there's a freely available MS Visual Studio *Express* edition that is more than adequate for your learning needs

Answer (score 1):

As @YePhicK said, and I'll emphasize, ***learn to use a debugger***.
Don't rely on guesswork or just eyeballs.

That said, I see something that, unless you really know what you're doing, is certain to break.

You have a loop using `j` as its index variable.
Then inside it, you have another loop that also uses `j` as an index variable.

```
      for(j=0;j<10001;j++){  // <----- j used here
         for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(j==x[i]){
               p[r++]=x[i];q[s++]=y[i];
            }
         }
         for(i=0,j=i+1;i<n,j<n;i++,j++){  // <----- j used here
            if(p[i]==p[j]){
               if(q[i]>q[j]){min[a++]=p[i]; max[a++]=q[i];}
               else{min[a++]=p[i]; max[a++]=q[j];}
            }
            else{min[a++]=p[i]; max[a++]=q[i];}
         }
      }
```

Also, you are using arrays called `min` and `max`.
There are commonly accepted macros called `min` and `max`, so if you redefine those you run the risk of a name collision.

Also, in code like this

```
{
  min[a++]=p[i];
  max[a++]=q[i];
}
```

it looks like you are putting empty spaces into arrays `min` and `max` by incrementing `a` twice.

Comment: Thanku for notifying me the faults. Still not printing anything.
Debugger is taking time to download.

Comment: @RachanaBagde: Run it under a debugger, like VC or GDB. If you don't know how, learn how. Single step into it, one line at a time. Display the variables. You can't just throw together a pile of code and expect it to work, or expect other programmers to spot all your bugs.

Comment: OK..sir.Thanku for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0,j=i+1;i<n,j<n;i++,j++)
```

The above for() statement contains the following (nonsensical) conditional expression:

```
i<n,j<n
```

Change this to one of the following:

```
i<n || j<n
```

or:

```
i<n && j<n
```

Also, variable 'float sum=0;' in 'main()' is unused; and main() should include a 'return(0);', or similar, at the end.